# Exponential time series predictions with confidence intervals in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-series, statsmodels, confidence-interval

**Context**

I have a short time series from a stochastic exponential growth process. I would like to compare the last few observations with a reasonable prediction from previous observations. This could, e.g., be computed from a normal distribution fit on the growth rate. The normal distribution fit is easily obtained, like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy
import scipy.stats

data = np.asarray([292, 291, 289, 295, 294, 313, 305, 308])
ds = pd.DataFrame({"data": data})
growth = (data[1:] - data[:-1])/data[:-1]
norm_mu, norm_sigma = scipy.stats.norm.fit(growth[:-2])
print("2.1%: {0:f}, mean: {1:f}, 97.9%: {2:f}, std: {3:f}".format(norm_mu - 2 * norm_sigma, norm_mu, norm_mu + 2 * norm_sigma, norm_sigma))
```

This is ca. mean=0.014, std=0.027, hence the 95.8% confidence (2 standard deviations) would be (-0.04, 0.068) in the first predicted period. Applied back to the time series, this would be (313*(1-0.04)=300.5, 313*(1+0.068)=334.3)

**Problem**

The first predicted period is easy; any confidence intervals can be obtained from the normal distribution for the growth rate and then applied back to the data series.

The problem are the following periods. Already in the second period the distribution of the expectation (the product of two random variates from an identical normal distribution) is not normal any more but a sum of two Chi squared distributions as explained [in this Maths:SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/397716). Later periods get more complicated.

Now, I am hoping that I am not the first person on this planet who was confronted with this problem. And that there might be a python module already that compute the desired confidence intervals - either exactly as explained above or following a similar reasonable way to predict exponential growth processes.

**Attempted solution with statsmodels**

Statsmodels provides this for linear timeseries as AutoReg and ARIMA. With these, confidence intervals can easily be generated and plotted in the way I want. Unfortunately, the predictions do not resemble an exponential growth process, presumably because the models are linear models. The confidence intervals turn out extremely narrow, especially compared to the above estimate of (300.5, 334.3) in the first period.

```
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AutoReg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

future_length = 2
future = {}

model = AutoReg(ds.iloc[:-2], lags=1)
model_fit = model.fit()
prediction = model_fit.get_prediction(len(ds)-2, len(ds)-3+future_length)
future['mean'] = list(ds.iloc[-3]) + list(np.asarray(prediction.predicted_mean))
future['95_low'] = list(ds.iloc[-3]) + list(np.asarray(prediction.conf_int(alpha=0.95).loc[:, 'lower']))
future['95_high'] = list(ds.iloc[-3]) + list(np.asarray(prediction.conf_int(alpha=0.95).loc[:, 'upper']))
future['50_low'] = list(ds.iloc[-3]) + list(np.asarray(prediction.conf_int(alpha=0.5).loc[:, 'lower']))
future['50_high'] = list(ds.iloc[-3]) + list(np.asarray(prediction.conf_int(alpha=0.5).loc[:, 'upper']))
future['time'] = np.arange(len(ds)-3, len(ds)-3 + len(future['mean']))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(ds.index, ds["data"], color="k")
ax.fill_between(future['time'], future['50_low'], future['50_high'], color="b", alpha=0.4)
ax.fill_between(future['time'], future['95_low'], future['95_high'], color="b", alpha=0.4)
ax.plot(future['time'], future['mean'], color="b")
plt.show()
```

[image: Example fit and prediction with AutoReg from statsmodels]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking a different approach and bootstrapping the confidence intervals. This is good enough for my present problem, but it would still be nice to be aware of an exact solution should one exist.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def bootstrap_confidence(start_value, growth_mean, growth_std, future_length, confidence_levels, number_replications=1000000):
    """
    Function for bootstrapping confidence intervals of an exponential growth process
    @param start_value (numeric): Value of the process at the start of the prediction
    @param growth_mean (numeric): Gaussian fit mu of the growth
    @param growth_std (numeric): Gaussian fit sigma of the growth
    @param future_length (int): How many periods to predict
    @param confidence_levels (list of float): List of confidence levels to return
    @param number_replications (int): Sample size for bootstrapping
    @return (pd.DataFrame): upper and lower value for each confidence level
    """
    array_list = [np.ones(number_replications) * start_value]
    for i in range(future_length):
        growth_rate_rvs = scipy.stats.norm.rvs(loc=growth_mean, scale=growth_std, size=number_replications)
        array_list.append(array_list[-1] * (1+growth_rate_rvs))
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for cl in confidence_levels:
        col_name_lower = "{0:.2f}".format(cl)[2:4] + "_lower"
        col_name_upper = "{0:.2f}".format(cl)[2:4] + "_upper"
        df[col_name_lower] = [np.quantile(sample,(1-cl)/2.) for sample in array_list]
        df[col_name_upper] = [np.quantile(sample,1-(1-cl)/2.) for sample in array_list]
    return df


data = np.asarray([292, 291, 289, 295, 294, 313, 305, 308])
ds = pd.DataFrame({"data": data})
growth = (data[1:] - data[:-1])/data[:-1]
norm_mu, norm_sigma = scipy.stats.norm.fit(growth[:-2])
print("2.1%: {0:f}, mean: {1:f}, 97.9%: {2:f}, std: {3:f}".format(norm_mu - 2 * norm_sigma, norm_mu, norm_mu + 2 * norm_sigma, norm_sigma))

future_length = 2
future = {}

future['mean'] = [data[-3] * (1 + norm_mu)**i for i in range(future_length + 1)]
future['time'] = np.arange(len(ds)-3, len(ds)-3 + len(future['mean']))
future_df = bootstrap_confidence(start_value=data[-3], 
                                 growth_mean=norm_mu, 
                                 growth_std=norm_sigma, 
                                 future_length=future_length, 
                                 confidence_levels=[0.5, 0.95])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(ds.index, ds["data"], color="k")
ax.fill_between(future['time'], future_df['50_lower'], future_df['50_upper'], color="b", alpha=0.3)
ax.fill_between(future['time'], future_df['95_lower'], future_df['95_upper'], color="b", alpha=0.15)
ax.plot(future['time'], future['mean'], color="b")
plt.show()
```

[image: Figure from example solution]